# How to make spectrogram's x axis start from 0 and end at full duration?

Tags: python, scipy, spectrogram

I created a 4 seconds length of data and plotted its spectrogram. nperseg was specified as 100. Due to this window length, the x axis does not start from 0 and end at 4s. Is there a way to align spectrogram's time axis with the original time domain signal?

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fs = 100
N = 400
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
y = 500*np.cos(2*np.pi*5*time)

f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(y, fs, nperseg = 100)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx, shading='gouraud')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.show()

plt.plot(time, y)
```

One example is shown in the figure below, both time domain signal and spectrogram start from 0 and end at 1s. [image: Time domain signal and spectrogram]

Comment: What do you mean with 'align' the axis? Changing the plot limits?

Comment: Original time domain signal's x axis starts from 0 and ends at full duration. I was asking if spectrogram's time axis can be changed as the same. Now it starts at the index of the center point of the first window

Comment: No, you can't because each time sample on your spectrogram requires a slice of the signal (window). Since the window must start and end within the given signal, the duration of the spectrogram is at most `(duration of signal) - (window duration - 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can plot as you did and use [xlim](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) to align the X axes.

```py
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fs = 100
N = 400
time = np.arange(N) / float(fs)
y = 500*np.cos(2*np.pi*5*time**2/2)

f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(y, fs, nperseg = 100)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx, shading='gouraud')
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
xlim = plt.xlim() # save the x limits of the first plot
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(time, y);

plt.xlim(xlim) # apply the saved limits to the second plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: This solution shortened the X axis of time domain signal, I added a picture to explain what is expected.

Comment: That's the only way I can do it. Having a spectrogram with the same duration of the signal require to compute the spectrum using one single sample. What can you tell me about the shahpe of a curve if you see only one point of it?